# Uninstall Slack Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, uninstall

I installed Slack from the .deb file provided by their website. But now I need to uninstall it. But when I type

```
sudo apt-get remove slack
```

It says

```
Package 'slack' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

When I search for 'Slack' in the Software Center, it doesn't show up. Does anyone know how to properly uninstall this?

Comment: Is the name of the file you downloaded "slack.deb"?

Comment: `dpkg --list | grep name` will show installed packages that has "name" in their designation.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You want...

`sudo apt-get remove slack-desktop`

Comment: It's been a while, but as written in the [official docs of Slack](https://slack.com/intl/en-gb/help/articles/360048367814-Update-the-Slack-desktop-app#linux-3) in the section "Trouble updating your desktop app", you should `rm -rf ~/.config/Slack && rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/slack.list /etc/default/slack` after removing slack for a fresh install

Answer (score 14):

If you are using snap package

```
sudo snap remove slack
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same response. And the only command which was working for me was from @Arul answer. But it was also not responding after few minutes. Then I had to find and end the slack processes from the background. After all this I applied the command provided by @Arul, it worked.

So basically if you've used snap and @Arul's command or uninstalling from ubuntu software is not working then try the following approach.

1. open system monitor
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5Gh1.png)
2. Search and end-process all the process with the name slack.
3. After ending all slack processes, try `sudo snap remove slack`. While this commands runs, you will be able to see that in the system monitor there will be some slack process after running the command. Don't kill/end-process them.

Finally search slack and I will be gone :)